Drawing state boundaries in county map in recent version
Using usmap, I have made a plot of values by US counties from some values stored in a variable county. Before I recently updated R and all my packages, I could easily create a county map with thick state borders and with state abbreviations using the following code:
library(ggplot2)
library(usmap)
centroid_labels = usmapdata::centroid_labels("states")
plotdf = data.frame(cbind(county$FIPS,county$SES)); plotdf[,2] = as.numeric(as.character(plotdf[,2])); names(plotdf) = c("fips", "SES");
plot_usmap(data = plotdf, values = "SES", color = NA) +  # color = NA removes county boundary lines
geom_polygon(data = usmapdata::us_map(regions = "states"), aes(x, y, group = group), fill = NA, linewidth = 1, color = "black") + # Keep state boundary lines
geom_text(data = centroid_labels, aes(x = x, y = y, label = abbr), fontface = "bold", colour = "gray12", size = 3)

With a few more lines to change colors and such, that would produce a picture like this:

However, as mentioned, since I updated packages, this doesn't work for me anymore. Specifically, it gives me and error that the object x wasn't found. Searching for an answer, it seems like others have stumbled into a similar issue. This means that I can draw the counties, but the code lines that creates state lines and state abbreviations no longer work. Removing what doesn't work, it will produce something like this:

Question: Is there any other way to draw state boundaries in this county map and also add state abbreviations?

Here is another approach that is closer to the original question asked.
library(ggplot2)
library(usmap)

# Extract data for states and counties
states_data <- us_map("states")
counties_data <- us_map("counties")
counties_data$SES <- rnorm(3144, 100, 100)
centroid_labels = usmapdata::centroid_labels("states")

# Map
plot_usmap("counties", color = 'NA') +
  geom_sf(data = counties_data,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geom, fill = SES),
          color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = states_data,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geom),
          color = 'black',
          linewidth = 1,
          fill = NA) +
  geom_sf_text(data = centroid_labels,
               mapping = aes(geometry = geom, label = abbr),
               fontface = 'bold',
               color = 'gray12',
               size = 3) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = 'white',
                       midpoint = 0) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')


Created on 2024-05-24 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you! This works perfectly and was easy to implement.
I tried around with your other solution, and I couldn't get something I was satisfied with (in particular, the usmap moves Alaska and Hawaii, so the sf state boundaries didn't fit there. Also, other than that, there were some slight variations in state boundaries between the two which looked a bit off).

Here is one approach using the packages geodata and sf.
library(tidyverse)
library(geodata)
library(sf)

# USA states
usa_shp <- gadm(country = 'USA', level = 1, path=tempdir()) %>%
  st_as_sf()

# USA counties
usa_county <- gadm(country = 'USA', level = 2, path=tempdir()) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  filter(ENGTYPE_2 != 'Water body') %>%
  select(COUNTRY,NAME_1,NAME_2) %>%
  rename(country = COUNTRY,
         state = NAME_1,
         county = NAME_2) %>%
  mutate(SES = round(rnorm(3137, 100, 50)))

# Centroids of USA states
centroids_usa <- usa_shp %>% 
  st_centroid(of_largest_polygon = TRUE) %>%
  select(ISO_1) %>%
  separate(ISO_1,
           c('country','state_abb'))
#> Warning: st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries

# Map
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa_county,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geometry, fill = SES),
          color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = usa_shp,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geometry),
          color = "black",
          linewidth = 1,
          fill = NA) +
  geom_sf_text(data = centroids_usa,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geometry, label = state_abb),
          fontface = 'bold',
          color = 'gray12',
          size = 3) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-125.5, -66), ylim = c(24.3, 49.5), expand = F) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = 'white',
                       midpoint = 0) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        legend.position = 'none')
#> Warning in st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)): st_point_on_surface may not
#> give correct results for longitude/latitude data


Created on 2024-05-24 with reprex v2.1.0
